# Mustache templating with an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, mustache

I am trying to template the following array of objects:

```
var arr = [{name:"Ryan Pays", url:"http://www.ryanpays.com"}, {name:"foo", url:"http://www.google.com"}];
```

I convert that array to an object like so:

```
arr = $.extend({}, arr);
```

Which gives me the following object:

```
{
0:{name:"Ryan Pays", url:"http://www.ryanpays.com"},
1:{name:"foo", url:"http://www.google.com"}
}
```

Using Mustache i want to enumerate over that object with the following template:

```
var template = "<h4>Your friends' choices</h4>" +
               "<ul>" +
               "<li>" +
               "<p><strong>{{name}}</strong> likes <a href='{{url}}'>this</a></p>" +
               "</li>" +
               "</ul>";
var html = Mustache.to_html(template, displayData);
$('.choices').html(html);
```

I don't seem to be able to do that.  I can get the first result like to print like so:

```
var html = Mustache.to_html(template, displayData[0]);
```

And so on but not both.

Link to fiddle of this issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/AtJDa/

Comment: "I mustache you a question.." -- sorry, I couldn't resist

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use the template for arrays :

```
var template = "<h4>Your friends' choices</h4>" +
    "<ul>" +
           "{{#arr}}"+
           "<li>" +
           "<p><strong>{{name}}</strong> likes <a href='{{url}}'>this</a></p>" +
           "</li>" +
           "{{/arr}}"+
    "</ul>";
var html = Mustache.to_html(template, {arr:arr});
```

Comment: That works like a charm.  Can't even see this feature documented.  How does this work?

Comment: Sorry i see what is going on now :)

Comment: Thank you nikoshr, this solved my problem when working with a JSON feed produced by github..

Answer (score 5):

You need to use Mustache's built-in iteration capabilities:

```
var template = "<h4>Your friends' choices</h4>" +
               "<ul>{{#friends}}" +
                 "<li>" +
                   "<p><strong>{{name}}</strong> likes <a href='{{url}}'>this</a></p>" +
                 "</li>" +
               "{{/friends}}</ul>";

var data = {friends: [{name:"Ryan Pays", url:"http://www.ryanpays.com"}, {name:"foo", url:"http://www.google.com"}]};

var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AtJDa/1/

the secret sauce is in the section declaration `{{#friends}}`

Comment: I don't really have access to the object at that level in the application.  My bad for not specifying that in the original question.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and I know what the solution is (use the built in iteration stuff) but my problem is that I have no "Handle" on the data like "friends" in your example.  From looking at the returned JSON in Firebug there is no name on the JSON array.  My collection just starts like `[{name:"Ryan Pays",` not `{friends: [{name:"Ryan Pays",` is there something I can do on my WebAPI server to name the collection?

Answer (score 0):

This series of posts was very helpful to me.   I'm building a Node.js app that uses Plotly.   I want to generate a sizable data set on my server, and need the browser to call Plotly.newPlot on that data.  The challenge was how to deliver the dynamic data for the Plotly call.   I had trouble passing the complex Plotly data object, but using Mustache's iteration on the component arrays works perfectly, even though I'm really dynamically generating the javascript.  On the server I map the simple arrays to arrays of Javascript objects:

```
tracexHash: data.x.map((value) => { return{'date': value} }),
traceyHash: data.y.map((value) => { return{'date': value} }),
tracezHash: data.z.map((value) => { return{'date': value} }),
tracecolorHash: data.marker.color.map((value) => { return{'value': value} }),
```

My html file contains javascript with Mustache iteration markup.  I included the ampersand before the field name to avoid HTML escaping since my data is string Date representations and the forward slash would get encoded -- and thanks to [Mustache: Globally disable html escaping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22910428/mustache-globally-disable-html-escaping) for that information.  It's a little laborious but achieved the objectives.

```
        let trace1 = {
            x: [ {{#tracexHash}} "{{&date}}" , {{/tracexHash}} ],
            y: [ {{#traceyHash}} "{{&date}}" , {{/traceyHash}}  ],
            z: [ {{#tracezHash}} "{{&date}}" , {{/tracezHash}}  ],
            mode: 'markers',
            type: 'scatter3d',
            marker: {
                color: [ {{#tracecolorHash}} "{{&value}}" , {{/tracecolorHash}}  ]
            }
        };
        let trace2 = {
            x: ["{{&first_pass_date}}"],
            y: ["{{&second_pass_date}}"],
            z: ["{{&interest_date}}"], 
            mode: 'markers',
            type: 'scatter3d',
            marker: {
                color: "darkblue",
                size: 20,
                opacity:60
            }
        }
        let data = [trace1, trace2];
        Plotly.newPlot('graphDiv', data, layout);
```