# Mustache: Globally disable html escaping?

Tags: javascript, mustache

Is there a way how I can (without modifying the sources of mustache) disable the HTML escaping? I'm using mustache for other things and dont want to have the following entities escaped.

```
var entityMap = {
  "&": "&amp;",
  "<": "&lt;",
  ">": "&gt;",
  '"': '&quot;',
  "'": '&#39;',
  "/": '&#x2F;'
};
```

Given a template like `foo '{{bar}}'` and a view `{ bar : 1 }`will produce `foo &#39;1&#39`.

Comment: How about running a "descaping" method after the page is fully loaded?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple. Mustache offers the possibility to override the `escape` function. This allows you to disable the escaping by simply returning the original value.

```
mustache.escape = function (value)
{
    return value;
};
```

As mentioned by others, you can also use the following notation to disable escaping.

```
{{{ test }}}
```

I leave the answer unchanged, since it might be helpful to implement your own sanitizing.

Answer (score 81):

If you are trying to just NOT HTML escape some strings, you just do **{{{xx}}}** instead of **{{xx}}**

As per:

http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html

So if you had a string that consisted of:

test => Q & A

Calling with:

```
{{ test }}
```

would give you:

```
Q &amp; A
```

..but calling with:

```
{{{ test }}} or {{ &test }}
```

Would give you just:

```
q & a
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it's not about the placeholders. My issue is that it also escapes the whole template.

Comment: How are you envoking the template? This works fine for me using a local template (inside a **<script>** in the same page): `var html=Mustache.to_html($('#templateListing').html(),marker);`

Comment: @Falselight what are you on about? the `& test` part is irrelevant - its just to show that & would be encoded / not encoded