# Nodejs - Issue while reading html contents from text file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am tying to read an html content from text file using the below code.All the html tags are replaced with some junk characters while reading it from file using fs module.

Can some one help me to understand what am i doing wrong?

`enter code here`File content

```
<h2 class="mb30">Bone Grafting</h2>
```

Response

```
﻿&lt;h2 class&#x3D;&quot;mb30&quot;&gt;Bone Grafting&lt;&#x2F;h2&gt;
```

code used

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile(filePath, function (err, contents) {
   //some code here
}
```

Encoding of the text file is utf-8

Comment: where is this `Response` coming from? the code you've shown will never output the content of the file, so, perhaps the problem is with the code you haven't shown - i.e. it's something to do with `//some code here`

Comment: You are right.I was trying to render html content returned from a file using mustache template engine.I dint knew that mustache will escape the text by default.Asnswer given in the following link solved my issue.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22910428/mustache-globally-disable-html-escaping

Answer (score -1):

Your missing to include the file format to read file details.

```
fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('/etc/hosts', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(data);
});
```