# Looping over an array of objects with mustache

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, template-engine, mustache

edit: updated this thread to clarify my question.

I make an ajax call that returns a dataset in json which looks like this:
[image]

Everything (including the correct column names) has already been taken care of via DB views so I wanted to write a script that just grabs a dataset and spits it out in a nicely formatted html table. This way the DB's table\view can be changed (columns added and removed) and the code will not have to be updated. I've been trying to get this to work with mustache but there doesn't seem to be a simple way of doing it. In the [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855078/mustache-templating-with-an-array-of-objects) I find of people using mustache with an array of objects they are all explicitly referencing the objects properties in the template. I don't know the number or name of the objects' properties (the dataset's columns) will be a head of time so I can't enter them statically in the template.

Right now I'm using two templates, one for the headers and one just for the table rows:

```
<script id="datasetTable" type="text/template">
        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    {{#headers}}
                    <th>{{.}}</th>
                    {{/headers}}
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table></script>

<script id="datasetTableRows" type="text/template">
                <tr>
                {{#rows}}
                    <td>{{.}}</td>
                {{/rows}}
                </tr>
</script>
```

And here is how I'm using it:

```
//Build table headers from dataset's columns
datasetCols = [];
for (var keyName in dataset[0]){
    datasetCols.push(keyName);
};

//Build table rows from dataset rows
var renderedTableRows = ''; 
var tplRows = document.getElementById('datasetTableRows').innerHTML;
datasetLength = dataset.length;
for (var i=0; i<datasetLength; i++) {
    var currentRow = dataset[i];
    var rowValues = [];
    for (var prop in currentRow){
        rowValues.push(currentRow[prop]);
    }
var renderedHtml = Mustache.render(tplRows, {rows: rowValues});
renderedTableRows += renderedHtml;
}

//render table with headers
var $renderedTable = $(Mustache.render('datasetTable', {headers: datasetCols}));
$renderedTable.find('tbody').html(renderedTableRows);

$(htmlContainer).html($renderedTable);
```

This works fine, but I really would like to simplify it further by using only one template. Can mustache process this in a more efficient way- without me having to explicitly reference the objects properties' names in the template?

I'd also like to add that I am already using mustache in a bunch of other places (code I don't feel like re-writing with a new engine right now) so if mustache can't do it I'll stick to pure js for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

I've not personally used moustache, but they're all very similar.

Also, since it is logic-less you really want to return a more useful format. I.e an array of arrays would be better in this instance.

[["234", "ddg", "aa"], ["and, so on", "and so on", "and so on"]]

But if you know that there will always be three columns returned, you could do something like:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
<thead>
   <th> Whatever your headers are </th>
</thead>
   <tbody>
     {{#.}}
      <tr>
         <td>{{col1}}</td>
         <td>{{col2}}</td>
         <td>{{col3}}</td>
      </tr>
     {{/.}}
 <tbody>
</table>
```

Or enumerate the object:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
<thead>
   <th> Whatever your headers are </th>
</thead>
   <tbody>
     {{#.}}
          <tr>
         {{#each dataSet}}
            <td>{{this}}</td>
         {{/each}}
          </tr>
     {{/.}}
 <tbody>
</table>
```

Also, when creating HTML in javascript, use an array, it's faster.

```
 var somehtml = [];
 somehtml.push('something');
 somehtml.push('something else');
 somehtml = somehtml.join('');
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but no. The whole purpose of this is to make it completely dynamic. I don't know how many columns there will be or even what the column names will be- look at what my code is doing. Also templating engines are not the same they have different features and syntax. That looks like handelsbars, I don't think mustache can do that ( please correct me if I am wrong).